# Jquery .select() with .live()

Tags: select, jquery, textinput

How do I make this trigger when I select the text in the input?

It has to be live/delegate

```
$('input:text').live('select', function () {
    alert("selected");
});
```

Updated to input:text by popular demand. I still do not get an alert message when selecting text in input boxes. The example on http://api.jquery.com/select/ gives me the result I want. I just need it to work on a .live()

Comment: You're aware that `:input` should be `input`? The first is a pseudo element, the second is a real element.

Comment: @David Thomas: See http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/ It's valid but not recommended to be used like this.

Comment: @Drackir, you're right; hence my comment to you below [@colinmarc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193441/jquery-select-with-live/6193463#6193463)'s answer. :)

Comment: @colinmarc what dosen't happen is an alert box saying "selected" when I highlight text in an input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCwpN/3/)(jsFiddle) in Opera, FF, Safari and Chrome. IE8 doesn't seem to like it, however.

I thought maybe it was because `.live()` binds an event handler to the `document` and it's possible IE doesn't have an `onselect` event on the document so I tried limiting the scope of it to the [body](http://jsfiddle.net/mCwpN/4/) and even to a [wrapper](http://jsfiddle.net/mCwpN/5/) element with no luck.

This could be a bug with jQuery.

Comment: And there lies my problem... I have to use IE.

Comment: @colemande: You could always add the event using `.select()` when the elements are created. Though, if you have MANY of them, this could cause issues since it means each one has an event handler (vs using `.live` which only has one).

Comment: SOLUTION: $('input:text').bind('select', function () { textSelected = true; });

Comment: @colemande: That's the same as using `.select()`. It will apply to elements already created but not to new elements added to the dom after the bind call. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCwpN/9/) (try highlighting the text in the last box added by JavaScript)

Answer (score 3):

You're selecting all inputs wrong. You should be using `$('input')`, if that's what you want to do.

Or even better, since only text inputs can have text selected in them, try `$('input:text')`

I think the issue lies in this quote from the `.live()` documentation:

> DOM traversal methods are not
>   supported for finding elements to send
>   to .live().

When you use only a pseudo-class, jQuery adds the everything selector (`*`), like `$('*:input')`, which might fail to delegate based on the method it uses to fill the result array. Just a shot in the dark, but the best I can do without knowing more about what's going wrong.

Comment: @Drackir, you're right (and +1), but for this usage it would be a little better to use `$('input:text, textarea')`, admittedly with the subjective disclaimer of 'in my opinion.'

Comment: @Drackir you're right, but I still think this might be the issue. See my edit.